# Entity Framework: Find related navigation property by FK property

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I need to find the related navigation property of a FK property.

This is my model:

```cs
public class Blog
{
    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}

public class Post
{
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }

    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public virtual Blog Blog { get; set; }
}

public class BloggingContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}
```

Now, I want to write something like this:

```
var context = new BloggingContext();
var navigationProperty = GetNavigationProperty(context, typeof(Post), "BlogId"); // returns "Blog"
```

I'm using EF 6.2 with code first.

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of research, I didn't find ant resource or sample how to do it, but I found a temporary solution with the following code, I don't know if it is the optimal way or there is exceptions with it.

```cs
public static string GetNavigationByForeignKey(this DbContext context, Type entityType, string fkPropertyName)
{
    var objectContext = (context as IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext;

    var entityMetadata = objectContext.MetadataWorkspace
        .GetItems<EntityType>(DataSpace.CSpace)
        .FirstOrDefault(et => et.Name == entityType.Name);

    var navigationProperty = entityMetadata.NavigationProperties
        .FirstOrDefault(prop => prop.GetDependentProperties().Any(dep => dep.Name == fkPropertyName));

    return navigationProperty.Name;
}
```

if someone have a better solution, I would be grateful.